# How do I find certain days of a month between two dates in Excel using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

Lets say I have two dates: `2024-01-16` and `2024-03-16`. On 15th of each month an event happens. In this case it happened `2 times` (on `2024-02-15` and `2024-03-15`).

How do I find number of events happened between dates using Excel formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of using `SEQUENCE()` function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B4</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(DAY(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B2))=B3))
```

---

If using older versions then could try the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(DAY(B1+(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,B2-B1+1))-1))=B3))
```

---